# django URL doubled

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

when i clicked the anchor tag going to the detailed view of my product the url is doubled.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/products/t-shirt/
```

i think it is supposed to be like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/t-shirt/
```

List.html

```
{% for object in object_list  %}
<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{object.title}}</a>
<br>
{{object.description}}
<br>
{{object.price}}
<br>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
description = models.TextField()
price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=19, default=39.99)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# For url when you click a product
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "products/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

from products.views import (product_view,
                            product_detail_view,
                            product_featured_view,
                            )

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'products/$', product_view),
url(r'products/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', product_detail_view),
url(r'featured/$', product_featured_view),

]
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, Http404

from .models import Product

def product_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'object_list': queryset,
        # 'featured': fqueryset
    }
    return render(request, 'products/list.html', context)


def product_detail_view(request, slug=None, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Not Found..")
    except Product.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        instance = queryset.first()

    context = {
        'object': instance
    }
    return render(request, 'products/detail.html', context)


def product_featured_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(featured=True)
    context = {
    'object_list': queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'products/featured-list.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your `Product.get_absolute_url` differently:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/products/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)
```

I would also suggest you declare it via `reverse` as it says here [`get_abosolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).